# Pointing nameservers through multiple providers

Tags: dns, cloudflare, amazon-route53, nameservers

I wanted to know if such a scenario is possible:

- I have a domain hosted in `GoDaddy` - say `example.com`
- I go to `Cloudflare`, create that domain, take the nameservers, and configure them in `GoDaddy`
- I go to `AWS Route53`, create hosted zone, take 4x NS records that were generated and insert them in `Cloudflare` as NS records separately

So its: `GoDaddy` -> `Cloudflare` -> `AWS Route53`

And now - should I be able to manage my domains via AWS Route53?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but it seems you have wrong assumptions on how the DNS works. Delegations do not work like that. Through your registrar you set the nameservers authoritative on your domain and they are listed by the registry. The zone is to be edited where those nameservers are, you can't then just put new `NS` records. Of course your question would be a ton better with real names involved.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah thats what I thought that my assumptions of this are wrong; now I get it - I could achieve what I want but with subdomains

Comment: Alternatively, in the setup described why do you need to use Cloudflare at all? Why not using Route53 nameservers directly at GoDaddy?

Comment: yeah I know; it's a long story and my question is more out of curiosity than real need :) I did exactly what you described - Route53 NS directly in GoDaddy

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it seems that doing what I described above is impossible for the root domain, like `example.com`.

Meaning that if in my domain registrar I point to different Nameservers for `example.com` only those are valid and I cannot configure NS records for `example.com` further. So:

1. I buy `example.com` at GoDaddy -> all good
2. I login to Cloudflare, add new domain, receive Nameservers: `a.ns.cloudflare.com` and `b.ns.cloudflare.com` -> all good
3. I go to GoDaddy and configure Nameservers to be those from point 2 -> all good
4. Now I login to AWS, go to AWS Route53 and generate HostedZone for `example.com`. I receive 4 Nameservers: `a.aws.com`, ... `d.aws.com` -> all good
5. Now I go to Cloudflare `example.com` domain records and try to configure the 4x `NS` records for those four I got from Route53 -> **thats NOT good**

In point 5 this is not going to work.

**However!**

It is possible with subdomains. So if in point 4. I would have created HostedZone for `test.example.com` I would have been able to go to Cloudflare and point `test.example.com` with NS records to those 4x Nameservers that I get from Route53 and manage `test.example.com` and `*.test.example.com` from Route53.

If I am wrong in anything please correct me!